# My computer motherboard support DDR2 RAM so may I choose any DDR2 RAM?

Tags: memory, ddr2

Installed RAM Information as follows:

```
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: CHANNEL_B
    Bank Locator: DIMM0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer1
    Serial Number: SerNum1
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum1
```

So my question is may I have any DDR2 RAM or is there have different types of DDR2 RAMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part you can use any DDR2, though some motherboards won't work well with specific makes/models/sizes of memory sticks. I have mixed and matched many different types of DDR2 in many boards, and rarely do I run into problems. Most motherboards are quite forgiving of different make/model of DDR2.

HOWEVER! I *very* strongly recommend that you go to your mother board manufacturer's website and get the Qualified Memory List or the equivalent. It will tell you exactly what make and model of DDR2 is known to work in your board. See if you can find some memory off of that list. If not, your next best option is to buy name brand memory - avoid the off brands. Get the more expensive name brand memory, I have found them to be much more reliable.

I also recommend using the same brand/model/size of memory sticks. Although I have mixed and matched different sizes of memory in many boards, from time to time I run into incompatibilities. To be safe, always use the same make/model/size sticks. With experience you will find you can mix and match, but there is no guarantee that will work.